# First GitHub pull request for typo fix - do I need to branch locally?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, pull-request

I am new to GitHub and have not found this question addressed directly.

I want to make my first contribution (not code, just some grammar corrections to a README). I've cloned the repository to my machine.

My question: I know I will eventually make a pull request. Locally, I'm on origin/dev... do I need to create a new branch and commit my changes there? Or should I work directly on the origin/dev branch?

Since it is a very minor fix (really just an opportunity to practice making a pull request, not adding a new feature or anything) I am unsure whether the owner would want it to be a completely separate branch. If I should git checkout -b new_branch_name, what should I call it? "README_grammar" or something like that?

There does not seem to be a master branch that I have access to, and some guidelines suggest that I should branch from master when contributing fixes, but when I do git checkout master, it *creates* a branch called master.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to put my thoughts regarding your post. As there is multiple question i am trying to go one by one.

#### Question 1

> do I need to create a new branch and commit my changes there? Or
>   should I work directly on the origin/dev branch?

I think if we are not the single person who is responsible for doing changes, we should always start a new branch whatever the minor change set we want to put in master. Even we are owner/maintainer of the branch or not.

#### Question 2

> what should I call it? "README_grammar" or something like that?

I personally prefer to add pre-fix tag regarding what is my work all about before my branch name. As this is a fix issue so i would prefer to add `Fix-README-Grammar-Mistake` so that responsible person can have an idea about my work even dig into the change set.

#### Suggestion

> There does not seem to be a master branch that I have access to, and
>   some guidelines suggest that I should branch from master when
>   contributing fixes, but when I do git checkout master, it creates a
>   branch called master.

Developing rule in a team project is to always up-date one's current directory with master branch and one should not create any replicate of it or one should not try to delete in from local. Though there should not any problem if anyone unfortunately, deletes from local branch. whenever we need to create a new-branch we always should do the following

```
git checkout master
git pull 
git checkout our-new-branch
```

Comment: Thank  you Shakil. This was helpful, and apologies for including more than 1 question. I ended up finding a branch that already existed called readme-improvements, so I checked out into that, made my changes, added, committed, pushed, then did the pull request! It's already been merged to the master, so I think everything went alright.

Comment: @a2fet thank you for your appreciation. If you think this is an accepted answer for your question can you please kindly accept it as an answer so that other people may know about the current condition of this question.